# How to add hidden or readonly parameter to ModelForm?

Tags: django

How to add hidden or readonly parameter to ModelForm?

forms.py

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Model
    fields = ['field']
```

Comment: check it out https://chriskief.com/2013/09/28/django-modelform-and-conditionally-disabled-readonly-fields/

Comment: could not follow the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm)::
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

# field_name is the field which you want to make readonly
    def clean_field_name(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.field_name
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['field_name']
```

Comment: This might also work:

```
```Meta:

readonly = ('field_name',)
```